# Checking inputs against list and appending to list of lists

Tags: python, list, compare

I have an unordered list, `A = [1, 4, 16, 22, 9, 2]` and an ordered list `p = [0, 6, 12]`.

I have created a list of lists `s = [ [] for i in range(n+1)]`.

I want to compare each element of `A` against the first element in `p`, then the second and so on.

If `A's` element is smaller than `p's` element I want to append this to the correct list in `s`. (so first list in `s` will be empty as nothing is smaller than 0, second list in `s` should hold 1,4,2. -- Eventually 0 will go into the first list, 6 into the second and 12 into the third. The fourth list will hold elements greater than 12.

(I need it to be generic and work for different list sizes, so `A` could hold 20 elements and `p` could hold 5 etc..)

I'm struggling to put this into action.
Please help!

Answer (score 4):

Since `p` is sorted, you can use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) for this (with `O(log(N))` complexity):

```
for a in A:
    s[bisect.bisect_left(p, a)].append(a)
```

Out:

```
[[], [1, 4, 2], [9], [16, 22]]
```